# Is there a way to use wildcard characters to find an exact match?

Tags: excel, vba

I understand the wildcard character can be used to find additional characters on top of a word when filtering. For example, if I am filtering on the word "Sales" I can replace my filter to "Sales*" to find additional characters beyond the first five. Is there a way to use a character to stop and filter on exactly "Sales" i.e. so that results "Sales Operations" would not be included?

I tried this, and i thought it was working, but came to realize it was not.

```
With Thisworkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    If .Range("A2").Value = "Sales" Then
        .Range("A2").Replace "Sales", "Sales?"
    End If
End With
```

Comment: Have you got some VBA already working on for "Sales*"? Please post it so we can have a tinker

Comment: When you perform a Find in Excel there is an option to *Match entire cell contents*. VBA would have the equivalent to this property.

Comment: `*` stands for anything prior or after the word, `?` stands for one character. "Sales ?????????" Would find Sales Operations if there are no more words with that length

Comment: * doesn't mean "prior", it means any sequence of characters from that position.

Comment: Andy with prior i mean `*Sales`prior the word Sales `Sales*` after the word Sales.

Comment: You could use `Instr`

Comment: Is there a symbol to cut off the find? Like the opposite of * or ?

Comment: @Chris2015 you need to use `?` stands for 1 character Sales1, Sales2, Sales3,... Sales10. If you use `Sales?` only the first Sales1-9 will be found. And using if statements with wild cards need `Like` instead `=`. Using `Like` makes it Case Sensitive.

Comment: I don't fully understand what your issue would be when filtering, something along the lines of `ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$A$4").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="=Sales"` would not return `Sales Operations`, but only exact matches of `Sales`

Comment: I am using an Advanced Filter so it is more like Criteria1:=fl.Range("filter")

Comment: So, if there is a way to make the range equivalent to "=Sales" that would work also, but I didn't know that route either

Comment: So your question is about Advanced Filter, not the Find or Replace feature?

Comment: I think either could provide a solution

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to use the wildcard feature. If you record a macro use the Replace feature, and choose Options and tick `Match entire cell contents` you will see code like this.

```
Sub Macro2()

    Cells.Find(What:="Sales", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt _
        :=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:= _
        False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate
    ActiveCell.Replace What:="Sales", Replacement:="Foo", LookAt:=xlWhole, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
        ReplaceFormat:=False
    Cells.FindNext(After:=ActiveCell).Activate
End Sub
```

It is `LookAt:=xlWhole` that achieves the entire match.

Answer (score 1):

## Replace Trouble

You haven't said it explicitly anywhere, but I'm assuming that you used your code:

```
With Thisworkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    If .Range("A2").Value = "Sales" Then
        .Range("A2").Replace "Sales", "Sales?"
    End If
End With
```

and the result was that it replaced e.g. `Sales Operations` with `Sales? Operations` which you didn't want to happen.

The `Replace` method has 8 arguments while you were using only the obvious first two:

`What` and `Replacement`

The reason behind your grief was that due to the last `Find` or `Replace` operation you performed, the 3rd argument `LookAt` was set to `xlPart` which means that it will find or replace any occurrence in a cell containing your `What` parameter, "Sales". This is easily fixed by changing your line to:

```
.Range("A2").Replace "Sales", "Sales?", xlWhole
```

Now, like `LookAt`, there are two more important arguments which **are saved each time a Replace or Find is performed**:

`SearchDirection` and `MatchCase`

which are also best set each time a `Replace` or `Find` is performed.

You should carefully study those two methods, because they are not as simple (easy) as one might think.